Split condition for nominalization pathway used only in certain verbs
There is a construction I would like to formally incorporate into one of my language's verb system, which involves rendering the main verb as a noun, which is then possessed by the participant that was previously the agent, and then re-incorporating it into a verb phrase as the complement of an auxiliary.
e.g. "He sleeps" -> "his sleeping is" or "I'm gardening" -> "my gardening is" or "you're getting dressed" -> "your dressing goes-along".
With "do" as the auxiliary I intuitively feel like you could derive a causative from this, if the possessed noun is made the object of the auxiliary instead of the subject: "he does my washing [of clothes/dishes/car etc.]" > "I make him wash/launder". As sort of an extension of the phrase "to do one's bidding".
What I like about this possessed nominalization strategy is that it causes the subject to be rendered as an oblique (genitive) argument, and I'm a sucker for quirky subject. You can even imagine how this could give rise to a change in morphosyntactic alignment (and I'm also a sucker for wacky morphosyntactic alignment), e.g. if this genitive subject becomes the norm for intransitives, you could see an erg/abs parent language give rise to a tripartite child language. Or if the ergative morpho-phonologically resembles the genitive, you could get a pattern that looks a lot more nom/acc, yielding split ergativity.
What I'm not sure of is what this sort of construction would probably be used for. I kind of want to make it the norm for specific tenses for specific verb classes so I can wring some ridiculous TAM-class-based split ergativity à la Georgian out of it. But I don't know which tenses/aspects or which specific verb classes because I don't quite grasp what pragmatic goal would motivate the nominalization step to begin with.
The only thing I know for sure is that it's a known antipassive construction (Andrea Sansò, Where do antipasssive constructions come from?, 2017), so maybe a voice thing? Mood? Focus?
What would this nominalizing pathway realistically get used to encode?

I think that the term light verb captures the point of this question. Specially, Iranian languages are infamous for their use of Light Verb Constructions, an this is a recent research paper on Light Verb Constructions in Iranian where you may find more inspiration for your conlang. Example 8a of that paper even includes a possessor as an agent.
Thanks to Petra Steiner for giving some useful hints here.
